# Input type file empty but form still submits?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been having so much trouble with this but I cannot figure it out. I have a form and I am validating it with jQuery. Everything works even the type of file == jpg, png but my validation to check if anything was uploaded isn't working. So i need it to stop if there was no file chosen.

```
 //begins check
$("#story").submit(function (e) {    
  if ($("#human-story").val() == '8') {
    var fd = new FormData();
    var fileObj = document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0];
    var filename = fileObj.name;
    var size = fileObj.size;

    fd.append('date', (new Date()).toString());
    fd.append('input', fileObj);
    var t = filename.substring(filename.length-3, filename.length).toLowerCase();

    var imgVal = $('#fileUpload').val(); //this is to grab the input type file value

    if(['png', 'jpg' ,'gif', 'jpeg'].indexOf(t) === -1){
        alert("Incorrect File -- Please upload an image");
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
      };

      if(imgVal==''){
        alert("empty input file");
        e.preventDefault();
      }//this part wont work ^^^ to see if no file was chosen

      alert("your story has been submitted. Thank you.");
  } else {
    alert("wrong answer");
    e.preventDefault();
  };
 });//end submit function
```

html:

```
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file"  id="fileUpload"> 
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human-story" name="human-story" placeholder="Your Answer" required="">
```

Comment: I don't believe that just calling `e.preventDefault()` from a submit handler will prevent the form from submitting. Try adding a `return false;` as well.

Comment: i tried this as well but it still submits. Its crazy because my validation even checks for the file extension but it cant do this simple value check. I just dont know what else I can try

Comment: Are you able to check if it actually hits your `e.preventDefault()`, or does it hit the "your story has been submitted" alert? Is your form actually submitting? Or do you just think it is because you get to the "your story has been submitted" alert? Because you're not returning in your `if (imgVal == '')` check, so the function would continue executing and hit that alert as well.

Comment: yea my form continues to submit but the `e.preventDefault()` in the if statement right before checking the file extension works correctly say if i choose an mp4 file. It is wierd because i feel like it completely skips the if(imgVal='') statement

Comment: That sounds right...you have a `return` in the extension check, so that would stop the submit handler there. I'm not sure why your form is still submitting. According to the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/submit/): "we can cancel the submit action by calling `.preventDefault()` on the event object or by returning `false` from our handler."

Comment: This line `var t = filename.substring(filename.length-3, filename.length).toLowerCase();` returns "peg" for .jpeg's.

Comment: @user3735633 thank you I do need to fix that up.

Comment: @Travesty3 So I have been trying but still cannot get it to stop submitting. do you have any other recommendations as to what I can try?

Comment: You could try changing your submit button to a `<button type="button">` with a click event, and call `submit()` on the form if it should be submitted.